# Using same angular js controller twice with django template on same page

Tags: django, angularjs

I tried to find the solution to this problem on stackoverflow and google but couldn't find it. The issue is using same controller twice on the same page and only the first controller mention gets invoked.

So I have a base template and main page. Now mainpage inherits two completely different blocks - sidebar block and main content block. both needs my controller - myController but the moment I use ngController with same controller name on the page twice on these two completely different divs only the first one gets executed.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/keshavagrawal89/356bb68068ac3ed4ae4e#file-samecontroller

```
<!-- base.html -->

<div>{% block sidebar %}{% endblock %}</div>

<div>{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>


<!-- MainPage.html -->

{% block sidebar %}
    <ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
        <li></li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController"> my page content</div>
{% endblock %}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Why do you use ng-app twice. Just put in on the common root for the both your controller blocks. You cannot use multiple ng-app's, atleast by declaration. Even if you would want to use it (say 2 different apps) you would need to manually bootstrap the last one.

Comment: What do you mean putting common root? I could have done that had they been inside one div somehow. But look at my base template. They are completely independent but the content inside may be dynamic and dependent on controller.

Comment: @PSL I have tried the angular.bootstrap to bootstrap the last one as you suggested but here the problem is that they use same ng-app :(. I can make two different controllers for them but app will be same and they don't share a common **<div>** to include ng-app once. Now with bootstrap last one gets the priority and works but sidebar stops working.

Comment: @PSL I am really sorry. I made some mistake. angular.bootstrap works just fine.

Comment: @PSL Could you post your comment as answer so that I can mark that as a right answer?

Comment: Sure Added as answer. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use multiple ng-apps in the same application. Ideally you would just put it in the root of your app or create an app including multiple apps and place it in the root, in the example below all the entities registered in both the apps will be loaded into the `myApp` module.

ex:-

```
 angular.module('myApp', ['App1', 'App2']);
```

But in your case it seems like your app may or may not be the same, so best way would be to [manually bootstrap your app](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization).

But remember when manually bootstrap your app it is generally not to use `ng-app`

```
angular.element().ready(function() {
   angular.bootstrap(elmRoot, ['myApp']);
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/TGTK4T?p=preview)**

> Note: You should not use the ng-app directive when manually bootstrapping your app.

Answer (score 1):

the only problem with your code is multiple ng-app's as PSL says on the comment.
ng-app declares the scope for DOM objects for angularjs to parse and it should be use once

typically in the html tag like

```
<html ng-app="app"> or <html ng-app>
```

i recommed using a name for the app module

[here is a working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Pl9HuBGdZhUdEiTSJTn1)

Comment: I could have done that but same base.html page would be used by multiple pages/modules and they will have different ng-app of their own and their respective controllers. So <body> tag is inside the base.html and I can't put any ng-app tag in that as its independent.

Comment: I used angular.bootstrap as PSL suggested and it worked. Thanks for your input as well though :)